# Table (ng-repeat) does not load correctly with multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a table that gets all of its columns--except for one--populated by one backend call. A separate call to the server is made to get data for the last column. What I’m noticing is that at times this data gets displayed correctly on the table, and other times it doesn’t. Likely because of the timing of the 2nd ajax call. Wondering what the right approach should be is to fix this problem. Here is what I have

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat=“item in ctrl.items">
  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.desc }}</td>
  <td><i class=“icon icon-check”></i> ng-class=“{ ‘active': ctrl.isActive(item) }”></td>
</tr>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
loadItems() {
  myService.getItems().then( (response) => {
       this.items = response;
       this.loadColors();
  });
}

loadColors() {
  myService.getColors().then( (response) => {
     _.forEach(response, (val, key) => {
          _.forEach(this.items, function(item) {
               if (item.id === key) {
                    item.colors = val;
               }
          });
     });
  });
}

isActive(item) {
    return _.some(item.colors, function (color) {
        return color === ‘green’ || color === ‘blue';
    });
}
```

The last column (icon-check) does not have the active css class applied consistently. It works sometimes after a page reload, and doesn’t at times. I must be doing something incorrectly here...I have tried wrapping `this.loadColors()` in a $timeout as well as in a $scope.$apply, but both don't seem to fix it.

Comment: I am lost, is this Angular or angularJs ?

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference until you mentioned it :) It's AngularJs 1.x

Comment: can you  chain with a second .then instead of        this.loadColors(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your output depends on the response of results from two different calls, you need to chain them so you would get result once both are complete.

```
loadItems() {
  myService.getItems().then( (response) => {
       this.items = response;
       myService.getColors().then( (colorResponse) => {
     _.forEach(colorResponse, (val, key) => {
          _.forEach(this.items, function(item) {
               if (item.id === key) {
                    item.colors = val;
               }
          });
     });
  });
  });
}
```

This should solve the issue.

**EDIT** I have modified my code, probably because items are getting assigned earlier. In modified code I moved it to the last step.

```
loadItems() {
      myService.getItems().then( (response) => {
           var items = response;
           myService.getColors().then( (colorResponse) => {
         _.forEach(colorResponse, (val, key) => {
              _.forEach(items, function(item) {
                   if (item.id === key) {
                        item.colors = val;
                   }
              });
         });
         this.items = items; //Assigning it to items after we have set the colors.
      });
      });
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to fix it. I reloaded the page 5 times, and only 4 of those times did the column get updated properly.

Comment: @Prabhu Can you check if second version fixes your issue.